# How to host my reactjs build directory on an existing asp.net web api

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing ASP.NET web API project, and i have a reactjs project.

I have done :

```
yarn build
```

in my reactjs project directory got a build folder which i can host.

I tried hosting it on wamp server and it's working fine.

Is there a way i can serve my build folder from my ASP.NET web API